# Tweepy + App Engine Example OAuth Help

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tweepy

Hi I am trying to follow the Tweepy App Engine OAuth Example app in my app but am running into trouble.

Here is a link to the tweepy example code: http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy-examples
Specifically look at: http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy-examples/blob/master/appengine/oauth_example/handlers.py

Here is the relevant snippet of my code [Ignore the spacing problems]:

```
    try:
  authurl = auth.get_authorization_url()
  request_token = auth.request_token
  db_user.token_key = request_token.key
  db_user.token_secret = request_token.secret
  db_user.put()
except tweepy.TweepError, e:
  # Failed to get a request token
  self.generate('error.html', {
    'error': e,
  })
  return


self.generate('signup.html', {
  'authurl': authurl,
  'request_token': request_token,
  'request_token.key': request_token.key,
  'request_token.secret': request_token.secret,
})
```

As you can see my code is very similar to the example. However, when I compare the version of the request_token.key and request_token.secret that are rendered on my signup page

I.e. the variables I output to the browser:

```
request_token.key
request_token.secret
```

Are not the same as the data stored in the datastore:

```
db_user.token_key = request_token.key
db_user.token_secret = request_token.secret
db_user.put()
```

As an example here is what I am seeing when testing:

Printed to the screen:

```
request_token.key: MocXJxcqzDJu6E0yBeaC5sAMSkEoH9NxrwZDDvlVU
request_token.secret: C7EdohrWVor9Yjmr58jbObFmWj0GdBHMMMrIkU8Fds
```

Values in the datastore:

```
token_key: 4mZQc90GXCqcS6u1LuEe60wQN53A0fj7wdXHQrpDo
token_secret: dEgr8cvBg9jmPNhPV55gaCwYw5wcCdDZU4PUrMPVqk
```

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Reference Links:

Comment: I think you missed part of a sentence there. If I understand you correctly, there's something different about the tokens you output and the ones you have in the datastore? Different how?

Comment: @Nick - I just updated the question with further information and an example of how the values are different. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to get Twitter followers-count for a single user using Tweepy (version 2.0) on Google App Engine (GAE) in Python (version 2.7).

```
# ----GAE MODULES-----------
import  webapp2
from    webapp2_extras       import jinja2
from    google.appengine.api import users
import  tweepy
import  urlparse
import  logging

# ----JINJA2 TEMPLATE----------
class TemplateHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):
        logging.info('calling jinja2 render function %s %s', self, filename)
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(filename, **template_args))

# ----CODE-------------------- 
class TwitterTweepyImplementation(TemplateHandler):
'''
All Tweepy related methods are handled in this class
'''

#All methods that expect HTTP GET
twitter_tweepy_impl_get_methods = {
                       '/tweepyimpl/oauthRedirect': 'redirect_to_twitter_for_user_to_enter_uname_and_pwd',
                       '/tweepyimpl/oauthCallback': 'handle_callback_from_twitter_after_user_authentication',
                      }

def get(self):
    '''
    All twitter specific get actions are handled here 
    '''
    #identify page to display from the path in the URL
    rcvd_url = self.request.path

    #to keep the code a little easier to understand, there are no security checks or exception handling coded added in 
    #this code example, so please add those on your own.

    #get destination method using key-value pair
    dest_method = self.__class__.twitter_tweepy_impl_get_methods.get(rcvd_url, None)
    if dest_method: 
        func = getattr(self, dest_method, None)
        if func:
            func()
            return


def redirect_to_twitter_for_user_to_enter_uname_and_pwd(self):
    """
    Twitter OAuth Redirection: redirects user to Twitter for entering user name and password
    """

    logging.info('redirect_to_twitter_for_user_to_enter_uname_and_pwd')

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, YOUR_OWN_REDIRECT_URL_AFTER_TWITTER_AUTHENTICATION)
    '''YOUR_OWN_REDIRECT_URL_AFTER_TWITTER_AUTHENTICATION: you can set this everytime above or once at twitter.com from where
       you get your Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. E.g., http://www.yourwebsite.com/tweepyimpl/oauthCallback'''

    #get Twitter redirect url where user enters credentials (uname and pwd)
    auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url(); #logging.info("auth_url = %s", auth_url); 

    #store temp credentials as browser cookies (these need to be stored in the browser so that after user completes authentication
    #at Twitter.com, when user is redirected to the return URL above by Twitter (= YOUR_OWN_REDIRECT_URL_AFTER_TWITTER_AUTHENTICATION)
    #your application server knows for which user this redirect is for).
    self.response.set_cookie('token_key',    auth.request_token.key)
    self.response.set_cookie('token_secret', auth.request_token.secret)

    #redirect user's browser to twitter auth URL where user can enter username and pwd 
    self.redirect(auth_url)

    return


def handle_callback_from_twitter_after_user_authentication(self):
    """
    Callback from Twitter after user enters user name and pwd at twitter.com URL
    """

    logging.info('handle_callback_from_twitter_after_user_authentication')

    #Twitter redirected browser here. Now read verifier and determine if user twitter authentication succeeded, failed, or was
    #canceled by the user 
    auth       = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
    verifier   = self.request.get('oauth_verifier', None); #logging.info('verifier = %s', verifier)

    #user canceled twitter oauth
    if not verifier:
        self.redirect('your_app_url') #add your own url here.
        return

    #fetch temp credentials from browser cookies (as set during redirect_to_twitter_for_user_to_enter_uname_and_pwd method).  
    token_key    = self.request.cookies['token_key'];    
    token_secret = self.request.cookies['token_secret']; 

    #now exchange temp credentials for user specific access token
    auth.set_request_token(token_key, token_secret)

    #parse access token string to extract the key and the secret
    access_token  = auth.get_access_token(verifier=verifier); logging.info('access_token  = %s', access_token)
    params        = urlparse.parse_qs(str(access_token), keep_blank_values=False)
    access_key    = params['oauth_token'][0];                 logging.info('access_key    = %s', access_key)
    access_secret = params['oauth_token_secret'][0];          logging.info('access_secret = %s', access_secret)

    #add access token information to the datastore for periodic fetch of Twitter information later on for this user, e.g., via a cron job. 
    user_obj               = UserTwitterAccessTokenStorageDatabase.get_by_key_name(users.get_current_user().email())
    user_obj.access_key    = access_key
    user_obj.access_secret = access_secret
    user_obj.put()

    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret) #this statement you can use later on to fetch twitter data for any user whose 
                                                     #access-key/secret you have stored in your database. For example, via a cron job.
                                                     #User does NOT need to be visiting your website for you to fetch twitter data for the user.

    #use tweepy api now to get user data from Twitter
    api  = tweepy.API(auth)
    me   = api.me()
    #display debug information
    logging.info("me = %s", me)
    logging.info('me.id_str = %s, name = %s, screen_name = %s', me.id_str, me.name, me.screen_name)

    #get followers count for this user        
    user = api.get_user(me.id_str)
    logging.info('num_followers = %s', user.followers_count)

    #you have the required information - in this code example followers-count. now redirect user to your app determined URL
    self.redirect('your_app_url') #add your own url here.

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                      ('/tweepyimpl/.*', TwitterTweepyImplementation)
                      ], debug=const.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use twice `request_token`, `request_token.key` and `request_token.secret`. The second time ( in `self.generate`) you should read their values from your database and not request them again.